# How to Quote an ICD 10 Chapter in Vancouver style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I want to quote a chapter from ICD10 in vancouver format. I have searched whole web for some references on this. But I could not find anything. I am a newbie here. Can some one please help.

This is the chapter title "Chapter XVI Certain conditions originating in the perinatal period (P00-P96)"

Comment: Do you really need to cite a chapter, rather than the entire classification system?

Comment: @Orion: I need to site chapter XVI, p00-p96

Comment: Why not using the book chapter format? http://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/Vancouver/chapter

Comment: @Emilie: there is no specific authors for those chapters.

Comment: Why not just cite the book as a whole in your reference list, then have your in-text reference be something like “In chapter 16 of the ICD-10 (World Health Organisation, 1992), the WHO says ...”? (Comment using APA style since I’m not familiar with Vancouver style).

Answer (score 1):

ICD-10 Classifications of Mental and Behavioural Disorder: Clinical Descriptions and Disgnostic Guidelines. Geneva. World Health Organisation. 1992.

This is my reference:
http://www.who.int/medicines/areas/quality_safety/ReferenceListEnsBal.pdf

Comment: The OP is asking about citing a specific chapter.